# Google Drive - DriveApp get video Thumbnail to SpreadSheet

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to organize a huge list of videos files in Google Drive, where I'm using the code below to list the JPG images.

```
function myFiles() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('MyImages');
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
var s='';
var cnt=1;
while(files.hasNext()) 
{
var fi=files.next();
var type=fi.getMimeType();

if(type==MimeType.GIF || type==MimeType.JPEG || type==MimeType.PNG)
{
  sh.appendRow([cnt++,fi.getName(),type,fi.getUrl(),'=IMAGE("' + 
getThumbNailLink(fi.getId()) + '",1)']);
}
} 
}

function getThumbNailLink(fileId)
{
var file=Drive.Files.get(fileId);
return file.thumbnailLink;
}
```

My question and problem is, is there a way to show the thumbnails for the videos files, like drive do in folder view? So the ideia is to link the file and show the file thumbnail in the spreadsheet helping to organize the collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to import "counter, filename, mimetype, link of file, thumbnail" for each video file to spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Thumbnail links from the video files can be retrieved using Drive API.
- You can retrieve the video files by using the mimetype like `video/mp4`.
- Collect the data of each file and import the collected data using `setValues()`.

  - This is more efficiency than that using `appendRow()` with the loop.

#### Modified script :

```
function myFiles() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('MyImages');
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var s = '';
  var cnt = 1;
  var values = []; // Added
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var fi = files.next();
    var type = fi.getMimeType();
    if (type.indexOf("video") > -1) { // Modified
      values.push([cnt++,fi.getName(),type,fi.getUrl(),'=IMAGE("' + getThumbNailLink(fi.getId()) + '",1)']); // Modified
    }
  }
  if (values.length > 0) { // Added
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values); // Added
  }
}

function getThumbNailLink(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  return file.thumbnailLink;
}
```

#### Note :

- In my experience, when the video files are uploaded to Google Drive, using Drive API, the thumbnail link can be retrieved from the files that the thumbnail can be seen.
- If you want to retrieve data from other mimetype of the video files, please modify `if (type == "video/mp4") {`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hello, thanks, but appears to not be working, I got a blank spreadsheet without any data. Do you know what could be? Thanks!

Comment: @John Mark I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about the detail information of "a blank spreadsheet without any data"? I couldn't understand about this mean. The modified script just imports values to a sheet of "MyImages". I'm not sure about other spreadsheet. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: when I run the code on the spreadsheet MyImages, nothing happens. Any data comes to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @John Mark I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I had used the mimeType of ``video/mp4`` as a sample, because I'm not sure the mimeType of video files you use. I thought that this might be the reason of error. So I modified my answer. Please confirm it. By using ``type.indexOf("video") > -1``, various types of video can be used. Please rty to run again. If you use other type of video files, please tell me.